# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in manacc.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm working with a new project and I'm using node.js with mongodb. In the project I'm trying **to get data from a database and show it in the table of manacc.ejs file. but it shows the error below:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in E:\etsp\nodetest1\views\manacc.ejs while compiling ejs
    at Function (native)
    at Object.Template.compile (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:455:12)
    at Object.compile (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:288:16)
    at handleCache (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:147:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:348:14)
    at View.render (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\express.io\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\express.io\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:504:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\express.io\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:798:7)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (E:\etsp\nodetest1\routes\index.js:297:9)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (E:\etsp\nodetest1\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:178:8)
```

Here is my `index.js` file get method to the `manacc.ejs` view

```
router.get('/viewusers', function(req, res) {
    var usersess=req.session.username;
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('users');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('manacc', { title: 'custermize',user:usersess,viewusers:docs});
});
});
    <%foreach(viewusers as var user) { %>
    <tr >
        <td>   <%=user.username %> </td>
        <td>   <%=user.name %>  </td>
        <td>  <%=user.email %>  </td>
                <a href="/editusers/<?php //echo $row['_id']; ?>">
                </a>
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" >
                </a>

    </tr>    
    <% } %>
    <%endforeach%>
    </table>
```

Comment: EJS (and JS for that matter) is fundamentally different from PHP, but you're mixing the two.